# How to create a sublevel in navigation menu in android?

Tags: android, menu, navigation, navigation-drawer, android-menu

I would like to achieve the same effect like this:

http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/

when you click on document/ tutorial/ support, the menu will go to sublevel menu. It is not a expandable listview, nor a submenu item below the parent menu title.

I have tried create the menu using navigation view like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
            android:title="Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:title="Perfil" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="More Options">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
                android:title="Forum" />
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_headset"
                android:title="Headset" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

The problem is , it does not go to sublevel when I click on the parent menu title. How to achieve that in android? Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you got any solution,me also trying this,If you done, please share it once,Advanced Thanks  for your response..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe, I archived the desired effect:

[image]

The idea behind is to `clear()` existing menu and re-`inflateMenu` every time user click on the menu item, which should lead to a submenu. (And on getting back - do pretty much the same)

As a root menu (`activity_main_drawer.xml`), I used this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_item1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Item 1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_expand"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Sub Menu to expand" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

This is a submenu (`activity_submenu_drawer.xm`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:title="Go Back"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_back"
        android:id="@+id/back_to_main"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/sub_item1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:title="Subitem 1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/sub_item2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:title="Subitem 2" />
</menu>
```

`MainActivity.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here's the `MainActivity` class (which do the switching):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        .....
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    ....


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_expand) {
            navigationView.getMenu().clear();
            navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_submenu_drawer);
        } else if (id == R.id.back_to_main) {
            navigationView.getMenu().clear();
            navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I've uploaded my test-project to my dropbox - [feel free to check it out](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6pfl9tipefoi8xa/SubMenuApp.zip?dl=0)

I hope, it helps

Comment: Have you got any solution,me also trying this,If you done, please share it once,Advanced Thanks  for your response..

Answer (score 1):

one idea i had was to have each menu item open another fragment with a transition.  Underneath, the navigation drawer is just a listview inside a fragment right ? so launch another fragment from the adapter of the navaigation drawer list.

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help you

[Sub menu menu sample](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/07/android-options-menu-submenu-group.html)

Answer (score 0):

if i face this problem. then i ll use whole header (costume designed) navigation drawer for the app. and add expandable list view or other animated or other why control which is my actual requirement.

the advantages of using custom nav. is that we can set design and functionality as we need. if simple list of menu then batter approach is that use default nav. drawer as defined in design support lib.